# how to save the value of the checkbox in a windows phone application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to get the Checkboxes that I have stay checked, even when I close the app or move from page to page.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An fast way would be this in XAML:

```
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" Checked="CheckClick" Unchecked="UncheckClick" />
```

In code behind:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (settings.Contains("CheckBox1Checked"))
            CheckBox1.Checked = settings["CheckBox1Checked"];
    }

    private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        settings["CheckBox1Checked"] = true;
        settings.Save();
    }


    private void OnUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        settings["CheckBox1Checked"] = false;
        settings.Save();
    }
```

Better would be using MVVM and binding like

```
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckbox1Checked" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to do this just incase you cared is to use String Settings for example

```
    private void checkBox7_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox7.Checked)
        {
            MySettings.Default.WSites = "1";
            MySettings.Default.Save();
        }
        if (!checkBox7.Checked)
        {
            MySettings.Default.WSites = "";
            MySettings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
```

Then in the Forum load

```
        if (MySettings.Default.WSites == "1")
        {
            checkBox11.Checked = true;
        }
```