# How to Save Checkboxes state in ListBox windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a list box and a checkbox inside list box. XAML code is as follows

```
  <ListBox Name="list_locationAddFinal"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxCheckedStyle}" LayoutUpdated="list_locationAddFinal_LayoutUpdated" Foreground="Black" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox   Visibility="Visible" Background="Black" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="item_name" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Padding="5,15,5,15" Width="400"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

now when user will check a checkbox i want to save checked state and when i will open my application the checkbox box is not showing checked 
thanks

and my backend code is follow

```
 public class SampleCheckedData
{
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Icon
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
 private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem checedItem = this.list_locationAddFinal.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as CheckBox).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;
        if (checedItem != null)
        {
            checedItem.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }`
  private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem checedItem = this.list_locationAddFinal.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as CheckBox).DataContext) as ListBoxItem;
        if (checedItem != null)
        {
            checedItem.IsSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should give some more input here. How do you bind to your model? How does the model look like (i.e. the object that has the `IsChecked` property)? Also show us the `Checked` and `Unchecked` method.

Comment: public class SampleCheckedData
    {
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Icon
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

Comment: Try saving the state in an localsettings or any persistent datatype. And then bind the checkbox IsChecked Property.

Comment: Hello Stephan sir please check my back end code that i am using with binding..

Comment: Sir AbsoluteSith can you please give me any example how i can do this

Comment: @user Ok. What about the `Checked` and `Unchecked` method? (Btw. you should edit your post instead of putting that code into the comment section ;) )

Comment: ok  Stephan sir let me update it

Comment: btw if i were u i will just use INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and the environment will take care for the rest

Comment: See Sharp  can you please expalin how i can solve it?

Comment: You can check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318037/how-to-save-the-value-of-the-checkbox-in-a-windows-phone-application)

Comment: Thanks AbsoluteSith for your support .but its not perfect solution for my problem bcoze my check box is inside listbox so i cant access it directlly.

Comment: Well if you use ObservableCollection, combined with for INotifyPropertyChanged interface for  your model, when the change is made to an item in the listbox it also will affect the collection, this is basic mvvm pattern

Comment: @user sorry the above link was not so useful but then [this](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7) might be of help. It tries accessing the checkbox using a visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you launch your App, all the variables/controls etc get initialized to their default values.

In order to "save" your Checkbox's state, you need to store the information into a place that does not always get initialized or in simpler words "does not reset".

One way in which this can be achieved is by using the **IsolatedStorage**.
It's similar to the Data-File Handling concepts that we use in some basic programming languages like C and C++.

**Use the checkbox's Checked and Unchecked events to write a particular value into your file. On the Page's Load event you can always open this file to check it's value and the set the control's state accordingly.**

You can find out an IsolatedStorage sample [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Isolated-Storage-WP8-f75779fc/view/Discussions).

The code for the Checkbox's events are somewhat like this:-

```
private void CHK_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var appStorage2 = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            string filename2 = "stored_value.txt";
            using (var file = appStorage2.OpenFile(filename2, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
            {

                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
                {
                    writer.Write("1");
                }
            }
        }

        private void CHK_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var appStorage2 = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            string filename2 = "stored_value.txt";
            using (var file = appStorage2.OpenFile(filename2, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
            {

                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
                {
                    writer.Write("0");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello Anmol Kumar Sir thanks  its working but the issue is that your example is checked all the checkbox and if i uncheck any checkbox and reopen app the unchecked check box is also showing checked

Comment: To solve the problem, simply detect whether the App has been launched for the first time or not.

You can do this by opening a random file say random_file.txt via the IsolatedStorage. Now when you do this, the App will obviously crash as you have not yet created the file random_file.txt and you are accessing it. So use Exception Handling mechanism and put the code in a try-catch block.

In the catch block create the file random_file.txt. Along with that also create the file stored_value.txt that has been mentioned in the above code.

Should work out fine.

Comment: Hi Anmol could you please send me any example regarding the issue please its urgent till now i am still working on that issue and cant resolve it